# XLS to PDF conversion without losing formatting

Tags: java, excel, pdf, apache-poi

I have a generic problem with a not-so-generic requirement.

I have to convert an Excel file into PDF with a catch that all the formatting of each cell in the excel file has to be retained as it is. No change allowed. Like if a cell is formatted as Currency/Accounting then by default negative values are displayed in round braces e.g.(8.5)  but when read from Java the value is -8.5. For numeric cell, value would be 0 but is displayed as hyphen (-).
Similarly for rest of the formatting types, the display changes.

As the cell has different cell types and the actual value in the cell is displayed according to the formatting applied on the cell, how to copy it in output PDF file?

Latest I learnt that DataFormatter is much useful in my case. So I wrote below code

```
DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
Cell c = row.getCell(i);
CellStyle style = c.getCellStyle();
cellvalue = df.formatRawCellContents(row.getCell(i).getNumericCellValue(), style.getDataFormat(), style.getDataFormatString());
```

One of the cell has formatting ***($* #,##0.00*);*($* (#,##0.00);*($* "-"??*);*(@_)** (0x2c). If the value in the cell is 0 then ideally it should display "-" but it displays as 0.0 only.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just open this file in MS Excel, and save it as PDF?

Comment: Requirement is to create a PDF file for values in each row in the excel sheet.

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if it isn't the latest, did you try upgrading?

Comment: Thanks @Gagravarr, that certainly helped. I updated to POI3.9 and it removed almost all the issues except one. In a cell with formatting as "Accounting" value 0.0 is displayed as "-" but program is returning 0.0. Any idea about that?

Comment: Try a recent nightly build / wait a week for 3.10, then report a bug if it's still there!

Answer (score 0):

First install the pdf software in your local system then run this code in excel vb application. Give the name as you wish... that's it..
Sub expf()
    Application.ActivePrinter = "PDF Complete on PDFC"
    ExecuteExcel4Macro "PRINT(1,,,1,,,,,,,,2,""PDF Complete on PDFC"",,TRUE,,FALSE)"
End Sub

Comment: Requirement is to create a PDF file for values in each row in the excel sheet. and from technology perspective, only Java is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Using [POI](http://poi.apache.org/) jar we can read excel . After reading for each row you can create PDF files using [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/). Also based on your requirements apply the styles for the pdf.

Comment: I have working code to write PDF file. Main problem is reading the value from XLS exactly same as it is getting displayed in MS Excel application.

Comment: Refer this link to know how to read XLS using POI. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/